# How do insert a file like this into a MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, text-files

This the file I am trying to store in the database. I want to get the title and comments stored. I do get it in, but it stores only the first line.
Please help, not really good with databases.

```
title : The Descent Part 2 comment : badbaz83 : No it wasn't as good as the first one, but a hell of a lot better than I first feared. Worth a watch, but don't expect it to stand up to the first film.

title : Supernatural comment : MissAyla : I loved this episode. :) I'm thoroughly enjoying the new style, just like the original episodes.

title : Soccer Mom comment : chantellel93 : it's only 10 min so if u smoke 1 its worth the laugh 2/5. xx
```

Comment: Does it iterate through all the lines? Is any exception thrown?

Comment: Parsing a plain txt file will be a pain in the *ss... Have you considered using XML files?

Comment: Where are you setting `id`? If `id` is the primary key it must be unique. If you want to autoincrement `id` you don't need to supply it in your insert statement

Comment: @mj_ no exception is thrown.. it only reads in the first line and stops.

Comment: Sorry to be a stickler for this, but what do you mean "stops"? The program crashes entirely? We could comment out the database insert line and just let it run through entirely and make sure that everything else works fine. The SQL itself looks okay. Can you try it in the MySQL admin/developer application (I don't remember what it's called).

Comment: @mj_ stops as in .. does not continue to read again.. only the first  title and comments is inserted.. it does not crash.. no exceptions are thrown. I will look into the MySQL admin/developer application you talked about. Thanks.

Comment: What is the table structure? Use `show create table scraped_comments \G` or [workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: @KCD .. this is what it shows..

| scraped_comments | CREATE TABLE `scraped_comments` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `movie_title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_comments` varchar(1200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Comment: And `System.out.println` is correctly outputting all lines?

Comment: @KCD .. yup! System.out.println correctly prints out all the lines.

Comment: @user872009 so did you find your problem and get your answer?

Comment: yes! thanks! sorry, haven't been on here for a while.. you were of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to split `line` into `Title` and `Comment` and assign an `id`. Try this (note it is case sensitive):

```
String s = line.toString();
Title = s.substring(8, s.indexOf("comment :")).trim();
Comment = s.substring(s.indexOf("comment :") + 10, s.length()).trim();
```

Then let us know where you get to.

I'm assuming you are trying to do this database insert ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2477/1/0) ).
To automatically assign an id you could set id as your auto_increment primary key (as per my example). You could then could make use of [executeUpdate(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

I'll try and update my answer when you supply more details of the problem.